# DELETE http://localhost:54178/api/employees 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using React Client with C# WEB API.

**REACT Function**

```
 const deleteThisEmployee = empId => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("id", empId);
    fetch("http://localhost:54178/api/employee", {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: formData
    })
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          // SUCCESS
        }
        // FAIL
      );
  };
```

WEB API Settings :

```
   public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {          
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            // add this to support JSON response and not XML
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
                .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

            // Enable Cors

            config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:3000", "*", "*"));  // React
        }
    }
```

And the Controller :

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    // .. Some other verbs

    public String Delete(int id)
    {
        // TODO
        Console.WriteLine("Got the Employee ID : " + id);

        // Continue with delete logic 
    }

}
```

When I try to delete a row I keep getting

```
DELETE http://localhost:54178/api/employee 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

I've checked some questions on SO that suggested to add in WEB.Config

```
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
```

But it didn't help.

Any idea what might cause this ?

Comment: are you passing an ID? your examples don't show one.

Comment: @C.M. Sure , in the `body` of the `fetch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be one (or both) of a couple things.

1. The route isn't being registered as `DELETE` automatically. You can fix this by adding using `[HttpDelete]` above your `Delete` action.
2. It's not looking for the `id` in the body. The `DELETE` method [*may* contain a body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE), according to the specs, but that doesn't mean ASP.NET supports it. (I can't remember off hand if it does or not) You can try passing it via the URL instead of in the body:

```
 const deleteThisEmployee = empId => {
    fetch("http://localhost:54178/api/employee?id=" + empId, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          // SUCCESS
        }
        // FAIL
      );
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You should tell the framework to look for a delete method with an Action Verb Attribute on the controller the method like so:

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    // .. Some other verbs


    [HttpDelete] //fixed
    public String Delete(int id)
    {
        // TODO
        Console.WriteLine("Got the Employee ID : " + id);

        // Continue with delete logic 
    }

}
```